# What is the name of the VS Code extension that shows the last commit message for each line of code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VS Code used to show the last commit message next to each line of code, but after I reset my Windows and re-installed VS Code, the extension was gone. I already installed Git History by Don Jayamanne, and I can commit and push to my Git repo but the commit message for each line of code is still not there.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Check if adding the [Git Lens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) plugin is enough to restore that feature.

I get most of Git features on VSCode from that plugin.

> Here are just some of the features that GitLens provides,
>
> - an unobtrusive current line blame annotation at the end of the line with detailed blame information accessible via hovers
> - ...

Comment: that's it!! thanks so much! I've been struggling with having to switch tabs and windows for months because I haven't found the right one. I wonder why I didn't think to ask in SO earlier. thank you SO.

Answer (score 1):

Install "Git Lens" extension